# Copying specific folder into subfolders with ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, typeerror, concatenation

I'm working on Arcgis 10.5 and I am trying to achieve this:

On my script, I want to make folders and subfolder, and also I want to copy one specific folder into several subfolders at the same time. My script is working well to make the folders and subfolder.

However, I get  the next error when the script tried to copy the folder I want :

> TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'Result' objects.

This my script:

I can't see where is the mistake so can somebody can give me a hand?

```
import arcpy
import os
import shutil
#Workspaces
arcpy.env.workspace = r'F:\FOLDER'
Folder_to_copy = r'F:\FOLDER\FOLDER1\FOLDER2\BASE_CHIH_MZA_UTM13_2018' #<--I want to copy this folder into the subfolders Sub1,Sub2,Sub3,Sub4

#Folder to make
Sub1_Folders = ['Sub1FolderA','Sub1FolderB','Sub1FolderC']
Sub2_Folders = ['Sub1','Sub2','Sub3','Sub4'] #<--The Especific folders where I want to copy my folder

#Result
Out_putfolder = r'F:\FOLDER\OutPutFolder'

#Field dbf to make subfolder
Tabla_dbf = r'F:\FOLDER\BRIGADISTA.dbf'
Field1 = 'BRIGADISTA'

Brigadistas = [row[0] for row in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(Tabla_dbf,Field1)]
Unicos_Briga = set(Brigadistas)

#Make folder and subfolders
for f1  in Sub1_Folders:
    Sub1folder = arcpy.CreateFolder_management(Out_putfolder,f1)
    for f2 in Sub2_Folders:
        Sub2folders = arcpy.CreateFolder_management(Sub1folder,os.path.join(f2))
        for tb in Unicos_Briga:
            tabladbf = arcpy.CreateFolder_management(Sub2folders,os.path.join(tb))
            Copyfolder = shutil.copytree(Folder_to_copy,os.path.join(tabladbf))

print 'Done'
```

This is the error show up

```
Runtime error 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 29, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.5\Lib\ntpath.py", line 90, in join
    return result_drive + result_path
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'Result' objects
```

Comment: You need to understand that all geoprocessing tools return a result object, one of its properties might be the name of a resulting featureclass or a value. So you are trying to concatenate an object with a string, which makes no sense hence the error. A typical error (which you are doing) is assuming the result of a tool is a dataset, no it is a result object which you can query for the output dataset:  read the help file on result objects.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the error, you need to use `.getOutput` off the result of your CreateFolder operation. This will return the path as a string so you can use it with concatenate or `os.path.join`

```
subfolder = arcpy.CreateFolder_management("c:/temp", "foo")
subfolder.getOutput(0)
>> 'c:/temp\\foo'
type(subfolder.getOutput(0))
>> <class 'str'>
```

Based on the code in your question, here is where I'd put `getOutput(0)`. I'd attach it directly to the CreateFolder call because you're assinging the output of that to a variable. So order of operations for your **sub1folder** variable means the tool runs then the result object is got and assigned to the variable.

```
for f1  in Sub1_Folders:
    Sub1folder = arcpy.CreateFolder_management(Out_putfolder,f1).getOutput(0)
    for f2 in Sub2_Folders:
        Sub2folders = arcpy.CreateFolder_management(Sub1folder,os.path.join(f2)).getOutput(0)
        for tb in Unicos_Briga:
            tabladbf = arcpy.CreateFolder_management(Sub2folders,os.path.join(tb))
            Copyfolder = shutil.copytree(Folder_to_copy,os.path.join(tabladbf))
```

Comment: Thank you for answer but I don't understand your idea. Where exactly I need to type .getOutput on my script

Comment: I used the code from your question with the piece you need.